# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lib'

Tags: reactjs, icons, react-icons

I forked react-icons in an attempt to potentially contribute.  I went through the process detailed in the github repository notes on how to contribute and preview, and I keep getting this error after running `yarn start`.

```
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
warn  - Invalid next.config.js options detected: 
  - The value at .assetPrefix must be 1 character or more but it was 0 characters.
  - The value at .experimental has an unexpected property, publicDirectory, which is not in the list of allowed properties (adjustFontFallbacks, amp, appDir, browsersListForSwc, cpus, craCompat, disableOptimizedLoading, disablePostcssPresetEnv, esmExternals, externalDir, fallbackNodePolyfills, forceSwcTransforms, fullySpecified, gzipSize, incrementalCacheHandlerPath, isrFlushToDisk, isrMemoryCacheSize, largePageDataBytes, legacyBrowsers, manualClientBasePath, modularizeImports, newNextLinkBehavior, nextScriptWorkers, optimizeCss, optimisticClientCache, outputFileTracingRoot, pageEnv, profiling, proxyTimeout, runtime, scrollRestoration, serverComponents, sharedPool, sri, swcFileReading, swcMinify, swcMinifyDebugOptions, swcPlugins, swcTraceProfiling, urlImports, workerThreads).

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/invalid-next-config
warn  - You have enabled experimental feature (publicDirectory) in next.config.js.
warn  - Experimental features are not covered by semver, and may cause unexpected or broken application behavior. Use at your own risk.

info  - Disabled SWC as replacement for Babel because of custom Babel configuration ".babelrc" https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/swc-disabled
> [PWA] PWA support is disabled
> [PWA] PWA support is disabled
info  - Using external babel configuration from /Users/patrickskinner/Desktop/SE/contribute_react-icons/react-icons/packages/preview/.babelrc
error - ./src/utils/icon.tsx:1:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-icons/lib'
> 1 | import * as RiLib from "react-icons/lib";
  2 | 
  3 | export const ALL_ICONS = RiLib["IconsManifest"];
  4 | 

Import trace for requested module:
./src/components/@core/sidebar/index.tsx
./src/pages/_app.tsx
```

I searched everywhere I could think of for details on "RiLib" and "IconsManifest", but I couldn't find anything.

For the instructions that I'm following, they're listed here under "Contributing": https://github.com/react-icons/react-icons

Thoughts?

I tried looking for any documentation on RiLib, but I couldn't find anything.